# w3c validator rejects custom icons despite specifications

Tags: css, w3c-validation

Edit : Following this publication https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/380 the bug is fixed https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/commit/eca30bb7e985a9027e01d310b1b9e5588ae4b2b9

the at counter-style rule allows you to create your own list styles.
Only, this seems to cause a problem with the w3c css validator. Is this legitimate? This is well supported by browsers, and it makes counter-style property useless, if it is legitimate.

Error message :

```
Sorry! We found the following errors (1)
URI : TextArea
38      Value Error : content icone is not a content value : counter(step,icone)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

You can try on https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

```css
.works {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
}

.works ol {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.works ol li {
  padding: 2.5rem 6.5rem 2.5rem 7.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 14px -5px #888;
  position: relative;
}

.works ol li::before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9356DC;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.works ol li::after {
  content: counter(step, icone);
  counter-increment: icone;
  list-style: icone;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.5rem;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.works ol li:hover {
  background-color: #f5edff;
}

@counter-style icone {
  system: additive;
  additive-symbols: "\f54e" 3, "\f0ca" 2, "\f3cd" 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Works</title>

  <style>
  ol,
  ul,
  menu,
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
</style>

  </head>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
  <div class="works">
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For information : [the MDN page of Content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) :

> Values
> counter()
>
> The value of a CSS counter, generally a number produced by computations defined by  and 
> properties. It can be displayed using either the counter() or
> counters() function.
>
> The counter() function has two forms: 'counter(name)' **or 'counter(name, style)'.** The generated text is the value of the
> innermost counter of the given name in scope at the given
> pseudo-element. It is formatted in the specified 
> (decimal by default).

[And in w3c page of content property](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html#propdef-content) :

> Counters may be specified with two different functions: 'counter()' or 'counters()'. The former has two forms: 'counter(name)'
> or 'counter(name, style)'. The generated text is the value of the
> innermost counter of the given name in scope at this pseudo-element;
> it is formatted in the indicated style ('decimal' by default). The
> latter function also has two forms: 'counters(name, string)' or
> 'counters(name, string, style)'. The generated text is the value of
> all counters with the given name in scope at this pseudo-element, from
> outermost to innermost separated by the specified string. The counters
> are rendered in the indicated style ('decimal' by default). See the
> section on automatic counters and numbering

Comment: Worth raising as an issue on the CSS validator, I think.

Comment: Thanks for you response but, how to ?

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/

Comment: Done: https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/380

Comment: The bug is fixed.